# Sending e-mail to Specific Address from Windows Phone 8

Tags: email, windows-phone-8

i want to send email from my Windows Phone 8 app to PARTICULAR e-mail address (user should now be able to specify)
i want to do so for password recovery.

the solution which msdn(given below) provides is not the one which i want,

```
 private void HyperlinkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        EmailComposeTask emailComposeTask = new EmailComposeTask();
        string pwd = (string)settings["user"];
        emailComposeTask.Subject = "Password Recovery";
        emailComposeTask.Body = "Here are your Login Credentials-"+pwd ;
        emailComposeTask.To = "emailaddress@provider.com";           

        emailComposeTask.Show();
    }
```

this code will show the email compose client in which the user can change the email address, which i dont want to allow.
please share any alternative to EmailComposeTask or anything else which i can use for password recovery.

Comment: You can't do this. Email compose task is ultimately a user task. You have to use 3rd party library to send email in background i.e. without user interruption.

Comment: can you tell me any 3rd party libraries using which i can send email in background ?

Comment: Please check http://www.geekchamp.com/marketplace/components/livemailmessage. If you using any kind of webservice in your app then you should use web service to send emails.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you want to send an e-mail to the user's email address for password recovery purposes. This assumes that you have your own email server that should send the actual mail, which means that you need to instruct your server to send the mail by means of some web services that you should put in place. Windows Phone API can't help you with this and doesn't provide what you're looking for.